# What does this mean? Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, html, forms

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Compile Error
>   Message: Can't use function return value in write context
>   line number:116
>   floor($BudgetPerPerson) = $TotalBudget / $NumberOfPeople;

```
label class="heading">How much is your budget? :</label>
<br><br>
<input name="TotalBudget" placeholder="Budget " class="form-control" type="text">
<br><br>
</center>
<!----- Including PHP Script ----->
<label class="heading">How many guest do you intend to invite? :</label>
<br><br>
<input name="NumberOfPeople" placeholder="Number Of People" class="form-control" type="text"><br><br>
</center>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
<!----- Including PHP Script ----->

 <?php
```

> this part i think is wrong

```
$TotalBudget= ($_POST['Budget']);
    $people = ($_POST['NumberOfPeople']);
    $BudgetPerPerson  = $TotalBudget / $people;
//Calculate the Budget Per Person
```

> ---

```
$BudgetPerPerson = floor($TotalBudget / $NumberOfPeople);



//The $BudgetPerPersonmust now fit a package price
if($BudgetPerPerson == "17") {
echo "You have Package A";
}
elseif($BudgetPerPerson == "19") {
echo "You have Package B";
}
if($BudgetPerPerson == "22") {
echo "You have Package C";
}
if($BudgetPerPerson == "20") {
echo "You have Package D";
}
if($BudgetPerPerson == "25") {
echo "You have Package E";
}
//Since Package D is the most expensive, if the $BudgetPerPerson is equal to or higher than 20 it will automatically select Package D
elseif($BudgetPerPerson >= "27") {
echo "You have Package F";
}
else {
//This code will execute when the price per package is too low
echo "The amount of people is too high for the budget, please increase your budget or reduce the number of people to receive a package quotation.";
}else {
//Calculate the Difference between the lowest package price and the offered price
ceil($Difference) = ((17 - $BudgetPerPerson) * $NumberOfPeople)
//This code will execute when the price per package is too low
echo "Your budget is too low for the amount of people. Please increase your budget by: $" . $Difference . " to be able to reserve a package";
}

?>
```

Comment: You can likely not assign a number to the result of a function like you are trying to do now - I vote to close

Answer (score 3):

You need to write it differently:

```
$BudgetPerPerson = floor($TotalBudget / $NumberOfPeople);
```

About the second problem, here's the error:

```
$TotalBudget= ($_POST['Budget']);
$people = ($_POST['NumberOfPeople']);
$BudgetPerPerson  = $TotalBudget / $people;
//Calculate the Budget Per Person

$BudgetPerPerson = floor($TotalBudget / $NumberOfPeople);
```

Your variable is called `$people` instead of `$NumberOfPeople`.

Change it like this:

```
$TotalBudget= ($_POST['Budget']);
$people = ($_POST['NumberOfPeople']);
//Calculate the Budget Per Person
$BudgetPerPerson  = floor($TotalBudget / $people);
```

Comment: i sorry i not very good in coding. can you show me how to declare this variable. $BudgetPerPerson = floor($TotalBudget / $NumberOfPeople); because i get an error said undefined variable.

Comment: @ZureenFarisya That means that either `$TotalBudget` or `$NumberOfPeople` or both do not exist yet in your code, or don't have a value. However, that is another question, you'll need to show some more code.

Comment: here i give the full coding

Comment: @ZureenFarisya edited the answer for your second problem

Comment: i dont understand.

Comment: You had the wrong variable name. `$NumberOfPeople` didn't exist, because you called it `$people` now I've changed it to fit the new name.

Answer (score 0):

You use a function on the left side of an assignment.